# Right way to get the children

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the below code and it works but what is the right way to get table onclick of add

**HTML**

```
<div> 
    <h4 class="titlebar">
        Skills
        <small><a onclick="return false;" href="/add/" data-span="3">Add</a></small>
    </h4>

    <div class="body">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr><td width="125"></td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
var TableBlock = $(this).closest('.titlebar').next().children('table');
```

`this` points to Add link

Comment: No, there is no click handler?

Comment: Give us a full HTML, or at least, the the `<h4>` parent.

Comment: You need to share more details. In given circumstances, even `$('.table')` would suffice. Please explain what you want to do.

Comment: you have a </td> too much in your example HTML, and what do you want to do when you click on add ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention who is the parent of `<div class="body">` and `<h4 class="titlebar">` which is critical.

```
$(this).closest('table-parent(the missing parent)').find('table');
```

`find` is better than `childern` because it will work even if the table get nested in future development.

If you want only the first matched table:

```
.find('table').first();
//Or
.find('table:first');
```

---

**Update:**
Based on your question update, I would add to the parent `div` a class or an `id`:

```
<div class="parent" >
    <h4 class="titlebar">
    ...
```

Then:

```
$(this).closest('div.parent').find('table');
```

If you can't change the DOM:

```
$(this).closest('h4.titlebar').parent().find('table');
```

Or:

```
$(this).closest('h4.titlebar').siblings('.body').find('table');
```

Comment: He said at first line `onclick of add` which means `this` is the anchor inside `h4` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @Joy. Maybe, but there is no click handler for it. But you're probably right. anyway, the missing parent is more critical.

Comment: @gdoron joy is right i have updated the question. Now my doubt is, is jquery clever enough to fetch only the first one. In your case if i have nested tables what will  happen

Comment: @WebDeveloper. Then you can use `.find('table').first();` or `.find('table:first');`

Comment: @gdoron how does sibling compare to next as suggested in other answer.

Comment: @WebDeveloper. `Siblings` will catch all the siblings not just the imidiate sibling. It's more generic